# iCal shows an event that the Google Calendar doesn't have?

Tags: ical, google-calendar, google-sync

I subscribed to a google calendar and all was going well until today that I saw an event on iCal and when checking on the web the event isn't there.

I synced with ⌘+R and ⌘+⇧+R and the event is still showing, the event is a repeating one on google calendar that in the date it shows on iCal was deleted on Google.

iCal version 5.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this same problem when I use ical for Outlook synching.  Drives me crazy.  Today I figured out a solution.  Go to your Google calendar and "Search" for the offending meeting (just use some key word).  In my case, it found the meetings.  I simply expanded the meeting info in the search results and it allowed me to delete the meeting.  Then, give Outlook some time to resynch and it will be gone.